# Comparing two number in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm sorry if it seems a very basic question, but I cant compare two file sizes where one file is being written continuously in batch script, it doesn't go beyond if statement, just get stuck there and comes out without doing anything.

```
:START
 copy C:\Users\Admin\ping.txt C:\Users\Admin\ping.partial
 set file="C:\Users\Admin\ping.txt"
 set parfile="C:\Users\Admin\ping.partial"
 ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
 FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
 FOR %%B IN (%parfile%) DO set parsize=%%~zB
 echo %size%
 echo %parsize%
 if %size% EQU %parsize%
 (
   ECHO file is complete > C:\Users\Admin\status.log
   ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
 )
 else 
 (      
  echo incomplete > C:\Users\Admin\status.log
  ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
   goto start
   )
```

What I'm doing wrong here. :(

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if cond ( 
...
) else (
...
)

if cond (...) else (...)
if cond (...) else command
if cond (...) else (
    ....
)
if cond (
    ....
) else command
```

The placement of the parenthesis matters. The `if` opening parenthesis needs to be on the same line that the `if` command. The `if` closing parenthesis needs to be in the same line that the `else` clause (if present). The `else` opening parenthesis needs to be in the same line that the `else` clause.

Answer (score 2):

`if %size% EQU %parsize%` causes error

```
if opp condition opp2 command
```

if you modify follow this this will work

```
IF %size% == %parsize%   ECHO file is complete > C:\Users\finoy\status.log   ping -n 5  127.0.0.1 > nul 
else echo incomplete > C:\Users\finoy\status.log ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the parenthesis after the if compare - it must be on the same line:

```
 if %size% EQU %parsize% (
```