# IF ELSE syntax error within batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch file writing and I'm writing a script that randomly opens one of three web pages and loops after a delay. I constantly get a syntax error when I run it, but I can't pinpoint where it is.

```
:main
@echo on
set location=""
set /A num=%random% %% 10 
if /A"%num%"=="0"
(
    set location="yahoo.com"
) 
else if /A"%num%"=="1"
(
    set location="msn.com"
)
else
(
    set location="google.com"
)

start "Chrome" chrome --new-window %location%
timeout /t 30 /nobreak >NUL
goto main
```

Help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is window use goto. It is crap

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is code according to good advices of [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) and [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo):

```dos
@echo off
:main
set location=
set /A num=%random% %% 10
if "%num%"=="0" (
   set "location=yahoo.com"
) else if "%num%"=="1" (
   set "location=msn.com"
) else (
   set "location=google.com"
)
start "Chrome" chrome.exe --new-window "%location%"
timeout /t 30 /nobreak >NUL
goto main
```

And here is the batch code following advice of [Ed Heal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal):

```dos
@echo off
:main
set location=
set /A num=%random% %% 10
if "%num%"=="0" set "location=yahoo.com" & goto OpenSite
if "%num%"=="1" set "location=msn.com"   & goto OpenSite
set "location=google.com"
:OpenSite
start "Chrome" chrome.exe --new-window "%location%"
timeout /t 30 /nobreak >NUL
goto main
```

See [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25343351) for an explanation of code `set "location=..." & goto OpenSite`.

---

This extra information is for [rudicangiotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3837788/rudicangiotti) because of his comment below answer written by [Middas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309672/middas).

It is not necessary for `if` and `else` with just a single command to use parentheses.

Therefore the code block

```dos
if "%num%"=="0" (
   set "location=yahoo.com"
) else if "%num%"=="1" (
   set "location=msn.com"
) else (
   set "location=google.com"
)
```

is parsed like

```dos
if "%num%"=="0" (
   set "location=yahoo.com"
) else (
   if "%num%"=="1" (
      set "location=msn.com"
   ) else (
      set "location=google.com"
   )
)
```

Perhaps this is easier to understand with C/C++ which does not require that `else` is on same line as command `if` or the closing parenthesis which belongs to the matching `if`.

A complete compilable C/C++ example code:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>    /* printf */
#include <cstdlib>   /* rand   */
#include <cstring>   /* strcmp */
#else
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* rand   */
#include <string.h>  /* strcmp */
#endif

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   const char* sLocation;
   int iNum = rand() % 10;

   if(iNum == 0) sLocation = "yahoo.com";
   else if(iNum == 1) sLocation = "msn.com";
   else sLocation = "google.com";
   printf("Number is %d and location is \"%s\".\n",iNum,sLocation);

   /* Some not really useful code to avoid warnings. */
   if(argc > 1)
   {
      if(!strcmp(argv[1],"/?"))
      {
         printf("There is no help for this small demo application.\n");
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Also in C/C++ there is no keyword for an `else if` statement as the `ElseIf` keyword in Visual Basic or `#elif` directive of the preprocessor.

Therefore the above condition block could be written also as:

```c
/* Variant 1: Same usage of brackets and indents like in first batch example. */
if(iNum == 0) {
   sLocation = "yahoo.com";
} else if(iNum == 1) {
   sLocation = "msn.com";
} else {
   sLocation = "google.com";
}

/* Variant 2: Same usage of brackets like in first batch example,
   but this time with indents as it would be 100% correct according
   to processing. It is not possible to use this syntax in batch
   files because the second if must be on same line as first else. */
if(iNum == 0) {
   sLocation = "yahoo.com";
} else
   if(iNum == 1) {
      sLocation = "msn.com";
   } else {
      sLocation = "google.com";
   }

/* Variant 3: Same usage of brackets like in second batch example,
   but without omitting not necessary brackets for first else block. */
if(iNum == 0) {
   sLocation = "yahoo.com";
} else {
   if(iNum == 1) {
      sLocation = "msn.com";
   } else {
      sLocation = "google.com";
   }
}

/* Variant 4: One more variant not possible in batch file,
   but using a very common style for C/C++ programmers. */
if(iNum == 0)
{
   sLocation = "yahoo.com";
}
else if(iNum == 1)
{
   sLocation = "msn.com";
}
else
{
   sLocation = "google.com";
}

/* Variant 5: This is variant 3 in coding style of variant 4. */
if(iNum == 0)
{
   sLocation = "yahoo.com";
}
else
{
   if(iNum == 1)
   {
      sLocation = "msn.com";
   }
   else
   {
      sLocation = "google.com";
   }
}
```

This code block could be written in C/C++ with a lot more variants taking the different styles for brackets and indents into account.

Really interesting for batch file coding are the variants 1 to 3 whereby variant 2 shows how variant 1 should really look like if it would be possible in batch files. But nobody brackets and indents `else if` blocks as shown in variant 3 as with several more `else if` blocks inserted the last `if` and `else` would be positioned thus far to right.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `else` on the same line as the `if`.  For example:

```
if 'true'=='true' (
    echo true
) else (
    echo false
)
```

Comment: Not quite. Example right, description not. The true-condition action-statement (or open-parenthesis, if used) must be on the same physical line as the `if`. The `else` keyword must be on the same physical line as the true-condition action-statement (or close-parenthesis, if used) and as the false-condition action-statement (or open-parenthesis, if used)

Comment: Furthermore, `else if` is not a valid statement. Batch scripting's conditional branches work only with `if` and `else` blocks. You can get a similar result setting another condition inside the `else` block, as in the following example: `if %VARIABLE%==condition1 ( dosomething ) else ( if %VARIABLE%==condition2 ( dosomethingelse ) else ( dosomethingelseagain ) )` Or even, you can also leave a blank `else` block: `if %VARIABLE%==condition1 ( do something ) if %VARIABLE%==condition2 ( dosomethingelse )`

Comment: [Rodolfo Cangiotti](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3837788/rodolfo-cangiotti), you are absolutely right. But in this case with just single command `if` in every `else` branch it is possible to use `else if`.

Comment: @Mofi, in this way, you mean that the prompt parses those statements as a condition without `else` inside another condition, don't you? `if %VAR%==cond1 ( dosomething ) else ( if %VAR%==cond2 ( do somethingelse ) )`