# Why does my batch file fail to get file size?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a Windows batch file that uses **ffmpeg** to convert whole folders with old *.flv videos into *.mp4 videos.

The batch file more or less works, but I want to do some test before deleting the source file. One of these test is that the output file should be at least 2/3 of the original file, but I can't get it to work.

Here's my bat file (with all the debugging echo lines included):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: get options and folder path
set opzione=%~1%
set cartella=%~2%
:: who's who?
if "%opzione:~3,1%"=="" (
    echo.
) else (
    if "%opzione:~0,1%"=="/" (
        echo.
    ) else (
        set opzione=%~2%
        set cartella=%~1%
    )
)
::echo.
::echo Cartella = %cartella%
::echo Opzione = %opzione%
::echo.



::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Check_path
    set FLV_FOLDER="%cartella%"

    if %FLV_FOLDER% == "" ( 
        echo ... Invalid
        goto :uscita
    ) else (
        echo ... OK.
    )

::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Check_Options (STILL W.I.P.)
    set Lista=0
    set Convert=0
    set Delete=0

    if "%opzione%"=="/c" (set Convert=1)
    if "%opzione%"=="/l" (set Lista=1)
    if "%opzione%"=="/d" (set Delete=1)

::echo Lista = %Lista%



::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Loop_path
@cls
echo Looping all .flv files in %FLV_FOLDER%...

    for /R %FLV_FOLDER% %%a IN (*.flv) do call :Converting_Function "%%a"
    goto :uscita



::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Converting_Function
    set infile="%~1"
    set outfile="%~dpn1.mp4"

    set outsize=0
    set insize=0
    set minsize=0

    if not %Lista%==0 goto :just_list

    echo Converting %infile% to %outfile%
    ffmpeg -v error -i %infile% -c copy -copyts %outfile%

    ::....................CHECKS........................................................
echo Errors from ffmpeg?
    if errorlevel 1 goto :error_ffmpeg

echo Do the outfile exist?
    if not exist %outfile% goto :error_exist

echo Is outfile big enough? 
    :: (say yes if outfile size > infile size*2/3)
    for /f %%S in (%outfile%) do set "outsize=%%~zS"
echo %outfile% size is %outsize%
    for /f %%S in (%infile%) do set insize=%%~zS
echo %infile% size is %insize%
    set /A "minsize=(%insize%*3)/2"
echo minsize is %minsize%

    if not %outsize% GTR %minsize% goto :error_size
    ren "%~1" "%~n1.todelete"
::               del /q %infile%
    goto :eof
:error_ffmpeg
    echo Convertion error
    pause
    if exist %outfile% del /q %outfile%
    goto :eof
:error_exist
    echo %outfile% does not exist
pause
    goto :eof
:error_size
    echo Size of %outfile% is 0
pause
    goto :eof
:just_list
    echo %infile%
    goto :eof

:uscita
pause
```

This is the output:

```
Converting "T:\C++Stuffs\_PROVACONV_\Monaco - Machine_#1 - Monday Morning.flv" to "T:\C++Stuffs\_PROVACONV_\Monaco - Machine_#1 - Monday Morning.mp4"
[flv @ 0000000000577320] Packet mismatch 107347968 1638 1638
Errors from ffmpeg?
Do the outfile exist?
Is outfile big enough?
"T:\C++Stuffs\_PROVACONV_\Monaco - Machine_#1 - Monday Morning.mp4" size is
"T:\C++Stuffs\_PROVACONV_\Monaco - Machine_#1 - Monday Morning.flv" size is
Operando mancante.
minsize is 0
0 non atteso.
D:\ffmpeg-20170204-b1e2192-win64-static\bin>
```

> ***Operando mancante*** means **Missing Operand**, **0 non atteso** means **Unexpected 0**

Why do I not have the file size in the variables? What is the missing operand?

Comment: Why do you use `for /F` to determine the file size? `for /F` is intended to read the file content; you should use `for` without the `/F` switch instead...

Comment: That was the problem! I used it 'cause i googled and used the accepted answer of a similar question.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted... while my question could be stupid, i've done my search, done my attempt, posted my code, not asked for a "do it for me" answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables `infile` and `outfile` are defined with file name being enclosed in double quotes. That is not recommended as explained in answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) But it is valid and works here as expected.

The command line to get file size of output file

```
for /f %%S in (%outfile%) do set "outsize=%%~zS"
```

is processed before execution by Windows command interpreter for example to

```
for /f %S in ("C:\Path\File Name.mp4") do set "outsize=%~zS"
```

It can be read on executing in a command prompt window `for /?` that `for /F` interprets the **set** (string between round brackets) as string to process if enclosed in double quotes except the option `usebackq` is used which is not done here. For that reason **FOR** splits up the string `C:\Path\File Name.mp4` into tokens using space/tab as delimiters and assigns the first token to loop variable `S`. So assigned to `S` for the example is `C:\Path\File`. The file size for this file can't be determined by Windows command interpreter as this file does not exist.

The solution is using **FOR** without option `/F`:

```
for %%S in (%outfile%) do set "outsize=%%~zS"
```

And the command line to get file size of input file

```
for /f %%S in (%infile%) do set insize=%%~zS
```

can be replaced by

```
set "insize=%~z1"
```

The help output on running in a command prompt window `call /?` explains this argument modifier for getting the size of a file passed as first argument to the batch file on calling it.

---

The help output on running `set /?` explains that in arithmetic expressions the **current** values of environment variables can be referenced by specifying the environment variables with just their names without using `%` or `!`. This works even within a command block beginning with `(` and ending with matching `)`.

The command line with the arithmetic expression

```
set /A "minsize=(%insize%*3)/2"
```

can result on `insize` not being defined in execution of

```
set /A "minsize=(*3)/2"
```

This explains the error message because there is indeed missing the left operand for the multiplication.

The solution is using the arithmetic expression as recommended by help of command **SET**.

```
set /A "minsize=(insize*3)/2"
```

This arithmetic expression never fails on evaluation. In case of environment variable `insize` is not defined, it is replaced by `0` on evaluation of the arithmetic expression as explained by the help.

See also [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

And please note that Windows command interpreter supports only arithmetic expressions with 32-bit signed integer values. So video files with a file size of 2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiB) or more cannot be correct processed by your batch code.