# Does anyone have a list of all characters unable to be used for variables in Windows Batch?

Tags: batch-file

When I try to make a variable, sometimes it won't recall when surrounded with %. An example is

```
@echo off
set firstvar= <o
set secondvar= ^. .^
echo.
echo %firstvar%
echo %secondvar%
pause
```

I'm wanting it to show up as

```
 <o
^. .^
```

but I get

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
ECHO is off.
 . .echo.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm really confused by this and I can't seem to fix it. I've narrowed down the problem to be something about the rules of assigning variables, and I'm guessing that the `<o` is being viewed as HTML or a website or something. I'm really confused with the second line though, why does it say ECHO is off? Why `. .echo.`? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, read the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for an explanation why it is advisable to use the syntax `set "variable=value"` on assigning something to an environment variable.

Second, read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of meaning of `<` in a Windows command line.

Third, caret character `^` is interpreted by Windows command interpreter as escape character like the backslash character `\` by many programming and scripting languages.

So the batch code with immediate environment variable expansion should be coded as:

```
@echo off
set "firstvar= ^<o"
set "secondvar= ^^. .^^"
echo/
echo %firstvar%
echo %secondvar%
echo Okay!
```

The strings to output are easier to code on using delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "firstvar= <o"
set "secondvar= ^. .^"
echo/
echo !firstvar!
echo !secondvar!
echo Okay^^!
endlocal
```

`^` and `<` must not be escaped inside a double quoted string and delayed expansion is used on outputting the strings of the environment variables.

**Note 1:** The two environment variables `firstvar` and `secondvar` do not exist anymore after the line with `endlocal` which is usually the last line in a batch file on using `setlocal`. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

**Note 2:** A percent sign `%` must be escaped with another `%` and not with `^` to be interpreted as literal percent sign and not as begin/end of an environment variable reference expanded during preprocessing of a command line or an entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` before running a command line.

**Note 3:** Any string including directory/file names containing an exclamation mark `!` is interpreted different on having delayed expansion enabled. Then the exclamation mark is interpreted as begin/end of an environment variable reference expanded delayed after preprocessing a command line/block. `!` must be escaped with two `^` on delayed expansion being enabled to be interpreted as literal character. The command line with `^^!` changes to just `^!` on first parsing it by Windows command processor. The command line changes to literally interpreted `!` on second parsing of the command line because of enabled delayed expansion.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?` ... Windows command interpreter
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And read also DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) why it is better to use `echo/` instead of `echo.` to output an empty line.

Last read also [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) for instructions how to see what the command interpreter really executes after preprocessing each command line/block.

See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Answer (score 0):

The caret `^` is the escape symbol, to echo it literally you have to double it `^^` once for every processing step (setting/echoing).
The redirecting/piping symbols `<|>` have to be escaped with a `^` caret.
If a string/variable to echo evaluates to nothing echo returns the status.
To avoid this use a different delimiter sign instead of a space `\/(:;` etc.

```
@echo off
set firstvar=  ^^^<o
set secondvar= ^^^^. .^^^^
echo.
echo:%firstvar%
echo:%secondvar%
pause
```