# Assist in Missing Operator - Batch-Coded Game

Tags: batch-file

This is the code in question. When I load my save file, I get the last saved stats, however when I move to advent2 I get 'Missing Operator' on each line. I'm not entirely sure on what to do.

(Also, just testing batch codes for a future text-based story game)

```
:startGame
cls
echo New Game / Load Game
echo.
echo Create New : (N)
echo Load Save : (L)
echo.
set /p NL=
if %NL% == n goto newGame
if %NL% == l goto loadGame
goto startGame

:loadGame
cls
echo Enter the name of your saved file.
echo.
set/p ldName=Enter:
(
set /p name= %name%
set /p exp= %exp%
set /p money= %money%
set /p deaths= %deaths%
set /p lvl= %lvl%
set /p hp= %hp%
set /p pwr= %pwr%
) < %ldName%.sav
goto advent2

:advent2
cls
echo Name: %name%
echo Experience Points: %exp%
echo Gold: %money%
echo Total Deaths: %deaths%
echo Current Level: %lvl%
echo Total Health Points: %hp%
echo Power Level: %pwr%
echo.
pause
goto advent3_1
```

Comment: A sample of your saved-game file should be edited into your question to assist in reproducing your results.

Answer (score 0):

Let us make the job of saving values of your batch game as simple as possible by using environment variables for your game variables which all start with same prefix string like `MyGame_`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "GameDataFile=%APPDATA%\MyGame\MyGame.dat"

if exist "%GameDataFile%" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=_=" %%A in ("%GameDataFile%") do if "%%A" == "MyGame" set "%%A_%%B=%%C"
    goto OutputValues
)

:NameInput
set "MyGame_Name="
set /P "MyGame_Name=Please enter your name: "
if not defined MyGame_Name goto NameInput

set "MyGame_Experience=0"
set "MyGame_Money=3"
set "MyGame_Deaths=0"
set "MyGame_Level=1"
set "MyGame_Health=5"
set "MyGame_Power=10"

:OutputValues
cls
echo Name: %MyGame_Name%
echo Experience Points: %MyGame_Experience%
echo Gold: %MyGame_Money%
echo Total Deaths: %MyGame_Deaths%
echo Current Level: %MyGame_Level%
echo Total Health Points: %MyGame_Health%
echo Power Level: %MyGame_Power%
echo/
pause

rem Other command lines for playing the game ...

:SaveValues
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%GameDataFile%") do md "%%~dpI" 2>nul
set MyGame_ >"%GameDataFile%"

endlocal
```

Microsoft recommends saving application data into a company or application related subdirectory of user specific application data directory of which path is defined by environment variable `APPDATA`. That is the reason for using `%APPDATA%\%~n0\%~n0.dat` whereby `%APPDATA%` is expanded by Windows command interpreter by the path of this environment variable and `%~n0` by name of batch file without path and file extension.

In case of this file exists already each non empty line of the file not starting with a semicolon is read by **FOR** and split up into three substrings (tokens):

1. First substring is from beginning of line to underscore which should be always the string `MyGame` if the file was not modified by somebody using a text editor. This string is assigned to loop variable `A`.
2. Second substring is the name of the environment variable between underscore and equal sign which separates variable name from variable value. This substring is assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `B`.
3. And third substring is everything after equal sign to end of line which is the variable value assigned to loop variable `C`.

The **IF** condition makes sure to load from the file for security just the environment variables starting case-sensitive with `MyGame_`. This **IF** condition would not be really needed, but it makes the batch file a little bit safer against data manipulations.

In general it would be good to check each value read from file for valid data after having them assigned to the environment variables. This data check is skipped in the demo batch code and instead the read values are output next.

But if the file does not already exist, the batch file user is asked for the name and the other environment variables are defined with default values.

Saving the values of the environment variables of the game is very easy now with all related environment variables starting with `MyGame_`. First the subdirectory is created in application data directory of the user with suppressing the error message output in case of directory existing already.
Then command **SET** is used to print all environment variables starting with `MyGame_` sorted alphabetically with redirecting this output into the file.

This method makes it very easy to add later additional environment variables starting with `MyGame_` as just the initialization must be done if not existing after loading the data from file. Loading and saving the additional variable starting with `MyGame_` is automatically done by existing code. Also it does not matter anymore in which order the values are stored in the data file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~n0` (name of batch file).
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564)
- Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)