# Windows batch os version check with if support

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, version

I'm making "BatchGameHub" for windows 10, and right now I'm making installer in .batch, but I don't know how to check windows version (10, 8, 7) and with support with if command.
Example what I mean:
(Command to check version)

```
if %winversion%== 10 goto start
goto win_not_compatible

:win_not_compatible
echo.
echo Your windows version cannot run gamehub!
echo [ Press any key to cancel installer... ]
echo.
pause>null
exit
```

Comment: Check out the [`ver` command](http://ss64.com/nt/ver.html). To capture its result use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the windows build numbers - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

And try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=4,5 delims=,. "  %%a in ('ver') do set "build_n=%%a.%%b"

set "Windows10=10.0"
set "Windows8.1=6.3"
set "Windows8=6.2"
set "Windows7=6.1"
set "WindowsVista=6.0"

if exist "%windir%\sysWOW64\" (
 set "bitness=64bit"
) else (
 set "bitness=32bit"
)

if not "%Windows10%"=="%build_n%" (
  goto :not_supported
) else (
  goto :start
)

:not_supported

echo not supported
exit /b 1

:start
pause
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it :3

Comment: It just for msecond oppened and closed... :(

Comment: @Arty - I've added a `pause`. You'll need to fill what you need to be executed after the `:start` label.

Answer (score 1):

To do what your question asks using `WMIC` this should work:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OV="
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'WMIC OS Where "Version<'4'" Get Version 2^>Nul') Do For %%B In (%%A
) Do Set "OV=%%A"
If Defined OV GoTo Start
Echo=
Echo Your windows version cannot run gamehub!
Echo [ Press any key to cancel installer... ]
Echo=
Pause>Nul
Exit /B

:Start
```

I used `<` with `4` to `GoTo Start` only on Windows 10, because a string comparison will find that the first character, `1` is less than `4` etc. *(Windows 10 or newer.)*

Answer (score 0):

A batch file like this could be used:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Get version of Windows enclosed in square brackets from command VER.
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%I in ('ver') do set "VersionWindows=%%I"

rem Get major and minor version and build number from version information.
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=. " %%A in ("%VersionWindows%") do (
    set "VersionMajor=%%A"
    set "VersionMinor=%%B"
    set "VersionBuild=%%C"
)

if %VersionMajor% LSS 10 (
    echo/
    echo Your windows version cannot run gamehub!
    echo/
    echo [Press any key to cancel installer... ]
    echo/
    endlocal
    pause >nul
    exit
)

rem Other commands for installation like:

set "ProcessArchitecture=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"
if %ProcessArchitecture% == 86 (
    set "ProcessArchitecture=32"
) else (
    if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe set "ProcessArchitecture=32"
)

echo Your are using Windows version %VersionMajor%.%VersionMinor%.%VersionBuild% %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
echo The installation process is running in %ProcessArchitecture%-bit environment.

endlocal
```

Please take into account the Microsoft documentation pages:

- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

It depends on the process starting the batch file if the batch file is executed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` or by 64-bit `cmd.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\System32` on Windows x64 (AMD64).

The following Wikipedia articles could be also helpful for this coding task:

- [List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)
- [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `ver /?`

And the name of the device **NUL** is `nul` with just one `L`. A line like `pause>null` results in redirecting the message into file with name `null` instead of device **NUL**. See also the Microsoft documentation pages [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) and [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) containing among lots of other useful information also a list of device names.

And last but not least read also DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) and avoid in future `echo.` in batch files and read about [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

Comment: I didn't tried but I think you are comparing the wrong token. Windows 11 also start with 10. esample of windows 11: 10.0.22621.3007. Windows 10 example: 10.0.19045.3930. The difference is >19 for Win11 in the first two digits of the build.

Comment: @Kintaro The question was asked and answered in 2018. Windows 11 was first time released in 2021. Neither the question nor any answer considers version information of Windows 11 for that reason. The game of the questioner runs obviously only on Windows 10 (or newer) and not on Windows 8.1/8/7 or older. It is therefore enough checking for main Windows version number being __less__ than 10. It can be expected that the game is compatible also with Windows 11. PS: I suppose the game uses console virtual terminal sequences requiring Windows 10 build 16257 or a later build (+ enabling it).

Comment: Opss I didn't notice the q&a date and time. I hope my comment can help some other people post-2021 :-)