# How to find which windows 10 build is installed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, build, version, wmic

I need to find which `windows 10` is installed via a batch file.

If it is between `1607` and `RS4 build` I will install `x.exe` if it is `rs4` or higher I will not install `x.exe`.

So I need an `if/else` statement to make it work?

```
threshold 1 1507 10240
threshold 2 1511 10586
redstone 1 1607 14393
redstone 2 1703 15063
redstone 3 1709 16299
redstone 4 1803 17134
redstone 5 1809 17650
```

Maybe to check if it is between `14393` to `16299` or I could just check if it is `1607` or anything else etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please add code that shows your working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch os version check with if support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513153/windows-batch-os-version-check-with-if-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible way, using `WMIC`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "VN="
For /F "EOL=V Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'WMIC OS Where "Version<'4'" Get Version 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=." %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "VN=%%B"
If Not Defined VN Exit /B
If %VN% GEq 11082 If %VN% LEq 16299 Set "VN="
If Defined VN Exit /B
Rem your install code goes here.
```

***Notes:***

There were three preview releases of `Threshold 1` which are not covered by my `WMIC` code: `6.4.9841`, `6.4.9860` and `6.4.9879`

The first release covered by my first `6` lines is the preview version of `Threshold 1` released on January 23 2015, `10.0.9926`; every other release since should work up to that point!

The following releases are covered by my answer:

- Redstone 1 Preview Releases: `10.0.11082` *December 16 2015* up to `10.0.14390` *July 15 2016*
- Redstone 1 Public Releases: `10.0.14393` *From July 18 2016*
- Redstone 2 Preview Releases: `10.0.14901` *August 11 2016* up to `10.0.15061` *March 17 2017*
- Redstone 2 Public Releases: `10.0.15063` *From March 20 2017*
- Redstone 3 Preview Releases: `10.0.16170` *April 7 2017* up to `10.0.16296` *September 22 2017*
- Redstone 3 Public Releases: `10.0.16299` *From September 26 2017*

**Edit**

This code is added for the purposes of an additional OP requirement in the comment section.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "VN="
For /F "EOL=V Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'WMIC OS Where "Version<'4'" Get Version 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=." %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "VN=%%B"
If Not Defined VN Exit /B
If %VN% GEq 11082 If %VN% LEq 16299 Set "VN="
If Defined VN GoTo SkipInstall
Rem your install code goes here.

Exit /B

:SkipInstall
Rem your code for Threshold or Redstone 4 goes here.
```

Comment: thanks for help but it iseems not working because versions are wrong and set vn is not a command

Comment: @EgeGökhanGürkan , when I answered your question, you had asked for up to `RedStone 3`, you've now changed it to up to `Redstone 4`, that's not my code's fault, it's yours. I've now adjusted the code to suit. As for the version numbers, I've included the preview releases in my code, your edit only uses the public releases. _(BTW, the preview release of Redstone 4 is shipping now at release 17133)_. Also despite me not having used `set vn` anywhere in my code, it is a completely valid command. Please do not change anything in my code except for the last line!

Comment: @EgeGökhanGürkan, I have found the typo related to the `Set VN=` error, I think you were referring to and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you can i change the code for if it is not between r1 and r4 then go to :seccondpart rather than exit? i dont want it to exit. i need it to continie if it is that or not. just to different ways..

Comment: @EgeGökhanGürkan, I've updated my answer, adding an **Edit** section to meet your additional request. _Please mark the answer as accepted, if it has solved the question originally posted_.

Comment: thanks it is great, it is solved thanks to you!