# How to modify environment variable value inside a loop?

Tags: batch-file

I have following code in a batch file:

```
set "start=2"

FOR /L %%a in (1,1,3) DO (
    FOR /L %%b in (%start%,1,3) DO (
        echo %start% Before Call
        call :changestring
        FOR /L %%c in (1,1,3) DO (
            REM Nothing
        )
    )
)

pause
Goto :Eof

:changestring
echo %start% Before Set
set "start=1"
echo %start% After Set
pause
goto :eof
```

What I want is that value of variable `start` referenced twice in second **FOR** loop with `%start%` changes from `2` to `1` after running subroutine `changestring` with the command line `call :changestring`.

The value of the environment variable `start` is modified in subroutine from `2` to `1` as output by the two `echo` command lines in subroutine. But in the second **FOR** loop the value is always `2` and does not change.

How to modify value of environment variable `start` on second **FOR** loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is output up to first execution of `pause` on running the batch file as posted in question from within a command prompt window without `@echo off` as usually used at top of a batch file to [debug this batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564):

```
set "start=2"

FOR /L %a in (1 1 3) DO (FOR /L %b in (2 1 3) DO (
echo 2 Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
) )

(FOR /L %b in (2 1 3) DO (
echo 2 Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
) )

(
echo 2 Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
)
2 Before Call

echo 2 Before Set
2 Before Set

set "start=1"

echo 1 After Set
1 After Set

pause
```

Windows command interpreted `cmd.exe` **interpreting** the batch file and executing the command lines outputs with no `echo off` always the command line before execution after preprocessing/parsing it as described at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

It can be seen that the command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` is completely preprocessed by Windows command interpreter before executing the most outer **FOR** command the first time. Both occurrences of `%start%` have been replaced during preprocessing the entire command block by the current value `2` of referenced environment variable. So the entire command block used next several times by **FOR** does not contain anymore an environment variable reference. Only the loop variable references remain in command block.

The help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window describes this problematic of all environment variable references done with `%variable%` being evaluated already during preprocessing. And help of **SET** describes also what is the solution for an **IF** condition and a **FOR** loop on which current value of environment variable changes within the command block or during loop execution: the usage of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

So let's use the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) to enable also delayed environment variable expansion in addition to command extensions which are enabled by default and needed here too.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "start=2"

FOR /L %%a in (1,1,3) DO (
    FOR /L %%b in (!start!,1,3) DO (
        echo !start! Before Call
        call :changestring
        FOR /L %%c in (1,1,3) DO (
            REM Nothing
        )
    )
)

endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

:changestring
echo %start% Before Set
set "start=1"
echo %start% After Set
pause
goto :EOF
```

The environment variable `start` is referenced now twice with `!start!` in second **FOR** command line and its command block which means with delayed expansion as being enabled in first line of modified batch file.

The output by Windows command interpreter up to first `pause` on running this modified batch file is now:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "start=2"

FOR /L %a in (1 1 3) DO (FOR /L %b in (!start! 1 3) DO (
echo !start! Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
) )

(FOR /L %b in (!start! 1 3) DO (
echo !start! Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
) )

(
echo !start! Before Call
 call :changestring
 FOR /L %c in (1 1 3) DO (REM Nothing )
)
2 Before Call

echo 2 Before Set
2 Before Set

set "start=1"

echo 1 After Set
1 After Set

pause
```

Both `!start!` remain in command block unmodified after preprocessing. So it really references now always the current value of environment variable `start` being modified during execution of the loops.

There is no need to replace `%start%` in the subroutine by `!start!` as it can be seen because both `echo` command lines are not within a command block and so each command line is preprocessed with replacing `%start%` by current value of environment variable just before immediately executing the command **ECHO**.

I hope the difference between **immediate** and **delayed** expansion of environment variables during preprocessing/parsing a single command line or an entire command block is clear now.

By the way: The name `start` for the variable is not good. `start` can be used as environment variable name, but there is also the command **START** which could be used in same batch file making it more difficult to distinguish between environment variable `start` and command `start`. Better would be as variable name for example `FirstNumber`.

An optimized code on which `FirstNumber` is used instead of `start` and on which the number is decremented using an **arithmetic expression** making it possible to reference an environment variable without usage of `%` or `!`  and nevertheless using current value of environment variable during evaluation of the arithmetic expression. The first number starting with `2` should be never decremented to a value lower than 1 being the reason for binary OR it with `1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FirstNumber=2"

FOR /L %%a in (1,1,3) DO (
    FOR /L %%b in (!FirstNumber!,1,3) DO (
        echo !FirstNumber! before decrement
        set /A "FirstNumber=FirstNumber - 1 | 1"
        FOR /L %%c in (1,1,3) DO REM Nothing
    )
)

endlocal
```

The output on running this batch file with `@echo off` at top is:

```
2 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
1 before decrement
```

Of course `set /A "FirstNumber=FirstNumber - 1 | 1"` could be here simply a standard string to environment variable assignment, i.e. `set "FirstNumber=1"`. But I wanted to demonstrated that environment variables can be referenced by just their names within an arithmetic expression to make use of current values of the environment variables during evaluation of the expression. This behavior is also described by help of command **SET**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Conclusion: Reading carefully the help or documentation of a command, application, or function to use is always good practice for a programmer or script writer to avoid problems on writing coding.

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question,because of your explanation, it makes me understand what really happened