# Batch file unexpected behavior for prompt

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file:

```
echo off
CD \
:Begin
set /p UserInputPath= "What Directory would you like to make?" 
 if not exist C:\%UserInputPath% (
mkdir %UserInputPath%
) else (
set /p confirm= "Do you want choose another directory?"
echo %confirm%
if "%confirm%"=="y" goto Begin
)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\>echo off
What Directory would you like to make?ff
Do you want choose another directory?n
y
What Directory would you like to make?
```

Look at output, Directory ff already Exists, as you see If 
I answer n to Do you want choose another directory? Variable
"%confirm% shows as y.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Suggest you use `setlocal`. `%confirm%` being `y` instead of `n`, is possible that the script executed previously in the same CMD instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows command processor substitutes all environment variable references using syntax `%variable%` within a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` before executing the command which uses the command block.

This means here that `%confirm%` is replaced twice by nothing on first run of the batch file before the command **IF** is executed at all. This behavior can be seen on running the batch file without `echo off` from within a command prompt window, see [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

One solution is using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as explained by the help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?` on an **IF** and a **FOR** example.

But much better is avoiding command blocks where not really necessary.
In this case usage of command **CHOICE** for the yes/no prompt is also better than `set /P`.

```
@echo off
cd \
goto Begin

:PromptUser
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Do you want to choose another directory (Y/N)? "
if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF

:Begin
set "UserInputPath="
set /P "UserInputPath=What Directory would you like to make? "

rem Has the user not input any string?
if not defined UserInputPath goto Begin

rem Remove all double quotes from user path.
set "UserInputPath=%UserInputPath:"=%"

rem Is there no string left anymore?
if not defined UserInputPath goto Begin

rem Does the directory already exist?
if exist "%UserInputPath%" goto PromptUser

rem Create the directory and verify if that was really successful.
rem Otherwise the entered string was invalid for a folder path or
rem the user does not have the necessary permissions to create it.
rem An error message is output by command MKDIR on an error.
mkdir "%UserInputPath%"
if errorlevel 1 goto Begin

rem Other commands executed after creation of the directory.
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Comment: Good explanation. Good details. Thanks!