# What to fix on my code with two IF conditions inside a FOR loop referencing an environment variable defined by the IF conditions?

Tags: batch-file

Could you please guide me how to fix my script to get the trace route results to some IP addresses?

I want to get the `tracert` results for **8.8.8.8** and **8.8.4.4**. I wrote the script below and it works fine:

```
@echo off
echo %date% %time%

SET DNS1=8.8.8.8
SET DNS2=8.8.4.4

for  %%i in (%DNS1% %DNS2%) do (
    echo ----------------
    echo tracert to %%i
    tracert -d %%i
)

echo %time%
exit
```

I want to add a function so that it can print host name automatically. I tried as below, but it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
echo %date% %time%

SET DNS1=8.8.8.8
SET DNS2=8.8.4.4

for  %%i in (%DNS1% %DNS2%) do (
    echo ----------------
    if (%%i == 8.8.8.8 set host=Google1
        %%i == 8.8.4.4 set host=Google2)
    echo tracert to %host%
    tracert -d %%i
)

echo %time%
exit
```

Could somebody please correct the code for me?

Comment: Two problems. The first being you need two if commands to set each variable. No parentheses are needed for that. The second is you will now fall into the infamous delayed expansion trap because you are creating environmental variables inside a parenthesised code block of the FOR command. This requires that you use a setlocal command to enable delayed expansion and you then reference those variables with exclamation point instead of percent symbols.

Comment: Dear Squashman. Thank you so much for your guidance. So I am the newbie, could you please help to guide me by writing the codes with the simplest algorithm so that the newbie likes me can understand easily? I am not the native English speaker so it's hard for me if just read your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file could be written like this:

```
@echo off
echo %DATE% %TIME%

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "DNS1=8.8.8.8"
set "DNS2=8.8.4.4"

for %%i in (%DNS1% %DNS2%) do (
    echo ----------------
    if %%i == 8.8.8.8 set "host=Google1"
    if %%i == 8.8.4.4 set "host=Google2"
    echo tracert to !host!
    tracert -d %%i
)

endlocal
echo %TIME%
exit /B
```

Windows command processor executes one command line after the other. How a command line is parsed before execution is described at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) What is executed finally after parsing a command line can be seen on executing a batch file without `@echo off` from within a command prompt window as described at [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

A command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` is parsed completely by `cmd.exe` before the command is executed with makes conditionally or unconditionally use of the command block. During parsing the command block all environment variable references using syntax `%variable%` like `%host%` are substituted by current value of the referenced environment variable. In this case `%host%` is most likely replaced by an empty string before **FOR** is executed at all if the environment variable `host` is not defined by chance on starting the batch file.

The help output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains when and how to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on an **IF** and a **FOR** example. In code above delayed environment variable expansion is enabled and used to reference the current value of environment variable `host` on iterations of the loop body command block on which the environment variable is defined and gets assigned a string value.

There would be also possible to use:

```
@echo off
echo %DATE% %TIME%

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "DNS1=8.8.8.8"
set "DNS2=8.8.4.4"

for %%i in (%DNS1% %DNS2%) do (
    echo ----------------
    if %%i == 8.8.8.8 set "host=Google1"
    if %%i == 8.8.4.4 set "host=Google2"
    call echo tracert to %%host%%
    tracert -d %%i
)

endlocal
echo %TIME%
exit /B
```

The command line `call echo tracert to %%host%%` is modified during the parsing step of entire command block by Windows command processor to `call echo tracert to %host%` and because of command **CALL** this command line is parsed a second time on each execution of the command block before **ECHO** command is executed resulting in printing the current value of environment variable `host` to console window.

But I suggest to use this much better code:

```
@echo off
echo %DATE% %TIME%
echo/

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "DNS1=8.8.8.8=Google1"
set "DNS2=8.8.4.4=Google2"

for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%I in ('set DNS 2^>nul') do (
    echo ----------------
    echo tracert to %%J
    echo %SystemRoot%\System32\tracert.exe -d %%I
)

endlocal
echo/
echo %TIME%
exit /B
```

One or more IP addresses and their host names are assigned to one or more environment variables starting with the string `DNS`. IP address and host name are separated by an equal sign.

The command **FOR** runs in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
set DNS 2>nul
```

Command **SET** outputs to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) all environment variables starting with `DNS` sorted alphabetically with `name=value` which means for this example:

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8=Google1
DNS2=8.8.4.4=Google2
```

The error message output by **SET** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on not finding any environment variable starting with the string `DNS` would be suppressed by this code by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `set` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with using option `/F` captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** in background command process and processes this output by ignoring empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon.

The captured lines start all with `DNS` and so there is definitely no line ignored as no line starts with a `;`.

**FOR** with using option `/F` would also split each line into substrings using space/tab as delimiter with assigning just first substring to specified loop variable `I`. But this line splitting behavior is not useful for this task.

For that reason the option string `"tokens=2* delims=="` redefines the line splitting behavior. Now `=` is used as delimiter between the strings instead of space and tab.

And instead of assigning the first `=` delimited string to loop variable `I` which would be the name of the environment variable, the second equal sign delimited string is assigned to loop variable `I` because of `tokens=2` which is the IP address.

And there is additionally assigned to next loop variable `J` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) the rest of the line after the equal sign(s) after second `=` delimited string without any further string splitting on an equal sign. So the host name is assigned to loop variable `J`, even on containing one or more `=` as long as not containing them at beginning of host name.

This code is obviously better as the `DNS` environment variables can be defined all at top of the batch file with IP address and host name and nothing must be changed on the command lines below because it simply processes from 0 to n environment variables starting with `DNS` and having at least a second `=` delimited substring.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `tracert /?`

Answer (score 2):

The proper use to test multiple conditions using an `IF` command is used in this code. As a best practice I always use quotes around string comparisons. Also note the use of delayed expansion with the `host` variable. This is required because you are creating a variable inside a parenthesized code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo %date% %time%

SET DNS1=8.8.8.8
SET DNS2=8.8.4.4

for  %%i in (%DNS1% %DNS2%) do (
    echo ----------------
    if "%%i"=="8.8.8.8" set host=Google1
    if "%%i"=="8.8.4.4" set host=Google2
    echo tracert to !host!
    tracert -d %%i
)

echo %time%
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: To be honest. You taught me the first lesson in windows cmd programming. All I have is a too basic coding knowledge!! Thank you so much, Squashman. Have a nice day!