# how to automatically close tinyweb console after running from batch file

Tags: batch-file, console

I'm using [TinyWeb](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/) server.
I run it using a batch file START_tiny.bat:

```
c:
cd\
cd tiny
cd bin
tiny c:\tiny\root 8080
exit
```

The problem is that after tiny.exe is executed, the console won't close so it hangs here:
[image]
I can manually close the console window, and it will continue to run as expected, but I was just wondering if there was a way in the batch file to make sure it closes after the program is invoked.

**EDIT**:
the solution was:

```
cmd /c start tiny c:\tiny\root 8080
```

Comment: Try using cmd /C start program_here. You might be able to isolate the initiation of it

Comment: You can change the first four lines to this: `CD /D "C:\tiny\bin"`.

Comment: "Try using cmd /C" 
good idea but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` halts processing of the batch file as long as `tiny.exe` is running and waits for its termination, even if this application is a GUI application not opening any window or opening a GUI window.

The command `exit` is not necessary at all and is just bad for [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

It would be better to use a shortcut file (*.lnk) to just start *TinyWeb* server. **Target** in properties of shortcut file would be `C:\tiny\bin\tiny.exe C:\tiny\root 8080` and **Start in** would be `C:\tiny\bin` or `C:\tiny\root` or whatever should be the current directory on starting *TinyWeb*. No console window is shown on `tiny.exe` not being a console application which I don't know as not having downloaded and installed this application.

The command `start` can be used in a batch file for starting *TinyWeb* server as separate process by `cmd.exe` without waiting for its termination.

**One** of the following command lines could be used in the batch file:

```
start C:\tiny\bin\tiny.exe C:\tiny\root 8080
start /DC:\tiny\bin tiny.exe C:\tiny\root 8080
start /D C:\tiny\bin tiny.exe C:\tiny\root 8080
start "TinyWeb server" C:\tiny\bin\tiny.exe C:\tiny\root 8080
start "TinyWeb server" "C:\tiny\bin\tiny.exe" "C:\tiny\root" 8080
start "TinyWeb server" /D"C:\tiny\bin" tiny.exe "C:\tiny\root" 8080
start "TinyWeb server" /D "C:\tiny\bin" tiny.exe "C:\tiny\root" 8080
```

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `start /?` and read the output help for an explanation of the above command lines.

The parameter `/D` specifies the **start in** respectively **current directory** for the started executable. It can be specified immediately after `/D` or separated with a space from the switch.

Command `start` interprets first string in quotes as window title. For that reason it is necessary to explicitly specify a window title in double quotes on one of the other arguments is enclosed in double quotes even if no console window is opened because of started application is a Windows GUI application. An empty title string specified with just `""` is enough for GUI applications started by command `start` as separate process.

The command line `cd /D "C:\tiny\bin"` can be used to change current directory to `C:\tiny\bin` even on current directory being on a different drive. The help output on running in a cmd window `cd /?` explains the parameter `/D` to change also drive if necessary and not only current directory on current drive.