# Batch for loop to execute java - how to dereference variable as part of command

Tags: java, batch-file

Given this file `myfile.txt`:

```
-Dvariable=a -Dvariable2=b -Dvariable3=c
-Dvariable=a -Dvariable2=b -Dvariable3=d
-Dvariable=a -Dvariable2=b -Dvariable3=e
```

and `batch.bat`:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
    C:\javapath\java.exe %%A -XX:..... -classpath....... main.Main
)
```

How can I make `%%A` dereference as program arguments?

With the above, the output is: (i.e. its just stopping after java.exe)

```
(C:\javapath\java.exe)
Usage: java [-options] class [args...] //etc....
```

---

With doing set first, I simply get spaces:

```
batch.bat:
set x=%%A
C:\javapath\java.exe %x% -XX:..... -classpath....... main.Main

output:
set x=-Dvariable=a -Dvariable2=b -Dvariable3=c
C:\javapath\java.exe  -XX:..... -classpath....... main.Main
```

Comment: Do not assign the string value assigned to a loop variable to an environment variable within a __FOR__ loop on not modifying the string value next. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `set /?` and read the output help explaining the reason as well as [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/). Run `for /?` for help/manual/documentation of command __FOR__. Don't use `A` as loop variable although it is possible. After reading about `%~aI` and the other modifiers you can perhaps imagine why `A` or `a` is not so good.

Comment: The command line `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("myfile.txt") do "C:\javapath\java.exe" %%I -XX:..... -classpath....... main.Main` should work as long as no line in the text file has default end of line character `;` as first character and `myfile.txt` is in current directory whatever is the current directory. I recommend to put the command `echo` after `do` and run the batch file from within a command prompt window to see the command line which would be executed with `java.exe`, see also [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Mofi.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in (myfile.txt) do (
    C:\javapath\java.exe %%I -XX:..... -classpath....... main.Main
)
```

Comment: __Note:__ The option `usebackq` is only needed if the file name of the text file is enclosed in `"` because of file name (or its path) contains a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. This option is not necessary on using just `myfile.txt` and not `"myfile.txt"` as I wrote in my comment above.