# Batch script - usage of FOR /F with spaces in command and usebackq

Tags: windows, batch-file

Pretty new to batch scripting. I need the output of a command to be assigned to a variable. I got to know about the FOR /F command. My command has spaces and also double quotes. So I tried using the usebackq option. But it fails with the error on the space.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"`) DO (
SET var=%%G
)

ECHO %var%

pause
```

**The failure :**

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As per other questions on StackOverflow, I did everything right - **usebackq** for the usage of back tick, **demlims=** to ignore spaces as a delimiter. I am not sure why it is still failing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the `D` in `D:\Program` actually in the output, or is that a typo and it's really `C`?

Comment: `UseBackQ` is not needed at all in that scenario either, so remove it and revert to the standard `'` command quoting style.

Comment: Sorry that was C: - Updated it now.

Comment: Perhaps like this: `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"^"') Do Set "var=%%G"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A command line within `'` or within `` ` `` on using `usebackq` is executed by **FOR** with option `/F` respectively the Windows command process `cmd.exe` processing the batch file in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line appended as additional arguments.

`ComSpec` is a Windows environment variable predefined with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` as **system** environment variable.

The help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains how the strings are interpreted by Windows command processor after option `/C` (execute command line and close) or option `/K` (execute command line and keep running).

The usage of backquotes is not needed here as the command line to execute does not contain itself one or more arguments with `'`. So it is possible to enclose the command line in `'`.

It must be taken into account for the command line to execute by **FOR**, [how the Windows command interpreter parses a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/), i.e. how the **FOR** command line looks after parsing and processing it by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which can be seen on [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and how the command line is passed as argument string(s) to the second `cmd.exe` instance executed in background.

There are at least following two solutions.

```
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('^""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"^"') do set "var=%%G"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('""C:\Program Files (x86^)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1^=D2" /b "Q1^=D3" /c "D5""') do set "var=%%G"
```

The first solution was suggested by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) and is the easier one. The entire command line is enclosed in `"` which `cmd.exe` started in background removes before processing and executing the remaining command line. The additionally added `"` at beginning and at end of the command line are escaped with `^` for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file to be interpreted as literal character and not as beginning/end of an argument string. So the argument strings between the two escaped `"` are interpreted normally by `cmd.exe` processing the **FOR** command line.

The second solution is more difficult to understand. The entire command line is also enclosed in `"` for `cmd.exe` started in background. But the double quotes are not escaped for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and for that reason this `cmd.exe` instance interprets the command line now as list of following argument strings:

1. `""`
2. `C:\Program`
3. `Files`
4. `(x86`
5. `)`
6. `\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe`
7. `" Get /a "`
8. `P1=D2`
9. `" /b "`
10. `Q1=D3`
11. `" /c "`
12. `D5`
13. `""`

The closing round bracket after `(x86` is not interpreted as literal character in this case because of being outside a double quoted argument string for `cmd.exe` processing the entire **FOR** command line. For that reason it must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character and not as end of **set** placed at wrong position before `'` marking end of the command line to execute.

The two equal signs are both outside a double quoted argument string for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. Therefore `cmd.exe` would interpret them as argument separator and would replace each `=` by a space character. That is not wanted here because of the arguments should be passed as `P1=D2` and `Q1=D3` to the executable and not as `P1 D2` and `Q1 D3`. So both equal signs must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character and not as argument separator by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Both solutions result in running in background with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` and 32-bit program files into `C:\Program Files (x86)`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5""
```

The background command process removes the first and last `"` and then runs

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"
```

It is possible to create in directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF` a batch file `XYZ.bat` containing just the command line `@echo %0 %*` and replace `.exe` by `.bat` in the batch file containing the **FOR** command line to see if the batch file is executed at all and with which parameters passed to the batch file. This helps to understand what is going on with removing `@echo off` and running the batch file with the **FOR** command line from within a command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

The posted line fails because of the additional quotes around parameters *after* the program name. One workaround is to embed the entire command line inside another pair of outer quotes (and escape reserved characters like `()` to `^(^)` because they now fall outside a quoted string).

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`""C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5""`) do (...)
```

As noted in a comment, `usebackq` is not actually needed in this case, and the same syntax will work if using regular quotes, instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use backticks or `usebackq` here, simply use single quoted string and double quote your paths.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"') do set "var=%%G"
```

Also note that the parenthesized `do` code block to set the variable is not needed, in fact, as far as I can see, you do not even need the variable as you could get away by just using the metavariable.

```
@echo off
set "prog=C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\DEF\XYZ.exe"
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"%prog%" Get /a "P1=D2" /b "Q1=D3" /c "D5"') do echo %%G
```