# When do batch scripts not execute all commands except for error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a batch script that successfully executed someone else's command, but my subsequent command did not continue. Why?
My script:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
echo %cd%
set Param=%1%
set resultDir=..\build\UnityXXXXX-%Param%-Mac

echo start build Editor
: This line is executing someone else's script!!!!!!!!
.\jam Editor -sCONFIG=release
: The previous script finishes executing without any error, but even then, the later scripts will not continue to execute!!!!!!!!

echo start copy to build dir
if not exist .\build\WindowsEditor\Unity.exe (
    echo the Unity is not build, build it first.
    pause
    exit
)
if exist %resultDir% rd /s /q %resultDir%
md %resultDir%
xcopy /s ..\UnityXXXXX\* %resultDir%\
xcopy .\build\WindowsEditor\Unity.exe %resultDir%\Contents\Unity.exe*

echo finish
pause
```

This image is the result of the run, as you can see here, the execution was successful, but the echo of my later script has no output and no execution
[image]

Comment: When you execute another script like you did, there is no "return" to the original script. The parser just hits the "End of Script" and stops processing. Use `call` to "execute and return": `call .\jam Editor -sCONFIG=release`

Comment: I recommend to use never just `exit` in a batch file, use instead `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` to exit just processing of current batch file instead of exiting Windows command processor independent on being started with option `/C` as on double clicking on a batch file or with option `/K` as on opening a command prompt window from within the batch file is executed and independent on calling hierarchy. `exit` without option `/B` is usually not good in a batch file, especially on [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) or calling a batch file from another batch file.

Comment: @Stephan This helps me a lot!