# How to use FFmpeg and GeForce Hardware to decode and encode 4K MKV movie to 1080p

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I am struggling with the instruction provided to convert a 4k Movie to 1080p so I can run it easier on my plex server.

I have a Geforce 1080Ti and have enable cuda and all the necessary options when building ffmpeg.

I keep getting a weird error and I am stuck at the below point.

Here is my code that I am working on currently

```
REM @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
COLOR 0A
TITLE CONVERT 4K TO 1080P USING GEFORCE HW

PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET "FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe"

FOR /R %%G IN (*.mkv) DO (
    "%FF%" -hide_banner -hwaccel cuda -y -i "%%~dpnG.mkv" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -pix_fmts yuv420p10le -vf scale='1920:-1' -c:a copy "%%~dpnG(1080p).mkv"
    )

ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

below is the error output I get when running the above command

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : 5.1
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Mulan_2020.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : mandtv.net
    encoder         : libebml v1.4.0 + libmatroska v1.6.2
    creation_time   : 2020-09-10T05:08:02.000000Z
  Duration: 01:55:08.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16704 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x1608 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 15933746
      DURATION-eng    : 01:55:08.652000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 165642
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 13760089087
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : En
      BPS-eng         : 768000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:55:08.704000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 215897
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 663235584
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English
      BPS-eng         : 35
      DURATION-eng    : 01:50:28.504000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1150
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 29135
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(ger): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : de
      BPS-eng         : 2
      DURATION-eng    : 00:03:07.062000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 53
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(ger): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : de
      BPS-eng         : 27
      DURATION-eng    : 01:54:16.482000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 933
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 23256
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:5(fre): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : fr
      BPS-eng         : 0
      DURATION-eng    : 01:40:51.510000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 21
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 380
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:6(fre): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : fr
      BPS-eng         : 29
      DURATION-eng    : 01:54:19.902000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 806
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 25098
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : es
      BPS-eng         : 2
      DURATION-eng    : 00:03:21.201000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 3
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 73
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:8(spa): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : es
      BPS-eng         : 30
      DURATION-eng    : 01:43:53.693000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 783
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 24134
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:9(ita): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : it
      BPS-eng         : 2
      DURATION-eng    : 00:03:08.522000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 67
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:10(ita): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : it
      BPS-eng         : 27
      DURATION-eng    : 01:54:16.649000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 784
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 23506
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:11(por): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : pt
      BPS-eng         : 27
      DURATION-eng    : 01:54:16.649000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 784
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 23202
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:12(por): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : pt
      BPS-eng         : 2
      DURATION-eng    : 00:03:08.522000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 61
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:13(rus): Subtitle: subrip (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : ru
      BPS-eng         : 0
      DURATION-eng    : 01:37:43.480000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 9
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 420
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:14(rus): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : ru
      BPS-eng         : 50
      DURATION-eng    : 01:44:17.000000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 850
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 39721
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:15(ukr): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : uk
      BPS-eng         : 50
      DURATION-eng    : 01:43:53.650000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 848
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 39165
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v50.0.0 ('Awakenings') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-09-10 05:08:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> ass (ssa))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_nvenc @ 000002306685ccc0] 10 bit encode not supported
[h264_nvenc @ 000002306685ccc0] Provided device doesn't support required NVENC features
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
COLOR 0A
TITLE CONVERT 4K TO 1080P WITH GEFORCE HW ACCELERATION

:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM CHANGE WORKING DIRECTORY TO THE SCRIPT'S DIRECTORY
PUSHD "%~dp0"

:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM MAXIMIZE CMD WINDOW
IF NOT "%1"=="MAX" START /MAX CMD /D /C %0 MAX & EXIT /B

:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM POINT FF VAR TO FFMPEG.EXE'S FULL PATH
SET "FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe"

REM RECURSIVELY SEARCH FOR VIDEO IN THE WORKING DIRECTORY
FOR /R %%G IN (*.mkv) DO (
    "%FF%" -hide_banner -hwaccel cuda -y -i "%%~dpnG.mkv" -c:v nvenc_hevc -preset p7 -tune hq -vf scale='1920:-1' -c:a copy "%%~dpnG(1080p).mkv"
)

:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE CMD WINDOW WHEN FFMPEG HAS FINISHED
COLOR 0E
ECHO=
ECHO FFMPEG HAS FINISHED & ECHO=
PAUSE
```

Comment: Why is [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled although not used by the batch file? That makes the batch file execution just a little bit slower as every command line on execution is parsed twice and file names containing `!` would not be processed correct. The command __EXIT__ at end of the batch file is useless and should be replaced by `COLOR` for that reason. It just makes it more difficult to [debug the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

Comment: See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: Neat thanks guys. I appreciate the tips. I will try out your suggestions.