# Nested For loop in windows batch script not working

Tags: batch-file, nested-loops

I'm new to batch script and have trouble with a very simple code.

I'm trying to print the changes of variables in the nested loop as below but it doesn't work.
(e.g. n_total : 5->10->15->...)

Also, ratio is the result of adding two numbers in a string form. (e.g. "5" + "5" = "55")

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A n_total=5
set /A step=100

for /L %%A in (step,100,1000) do call(
    for /L %%B in (n_total,5,30) do call(
        set n_c=%%B/2
        set n_d=%%B - !n_c!
        set /A ratio=!n_d! + !n_c!
        echo %%B
        echo %n_c%
        echo %ratio%
```

Only

```
Some kind of error?
%B
%B/2
```

shows up in the executed result.
Please let me know what's wrong with my code. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have nested loops. What's `call(` supposed to do?

Comment: To be clear: your first `for` does ten times `call(` (which basically sets errorlevel to zero). The loop ends then. The second `for` does the same thing six times. The loop ends then. The following `set` command gives an error, because `%%B` doesn't exist anymore (because the defining loop has ended). Etc.

Comment: Replace both `call(` by just `(`. Remove `/A` on `set /A n_total=5` and on `set /A step=100` whereby it would be even better to use `set "n_total=5"` and `set "step=100"`. For the reason of this change see my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) `(step,100,1000)` must be changed to `(%step%,100,1000)` to reference the value of environment variable `step` as defined above. `(n_total,5,30)` must be changed to `(%n_total%,5,30)` for the same reason.

Comment: `set n_c=%%B/2` misses the option `/A` (arithmetic expression) to really evaluate the arithmetic expression, i.e. there must be used `set /A n_c=%%B/2`. `set n_d=%%B - !n_c!` must be changed to `set /A n_d=%%B - n_c` to evaluate this arithmetic expression. I strongly recommend to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the entire output usage help and run `set /?` and read again the entire output usage help explaining when and how to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and how to use an arithmetic expression.

Comment: `echo %n_c%` must be coded `echo !n_c!` or `set n_c` to get output this environment variable with name and current value. `echo %ratio%` must be coded `echo !ratio!` or `set ratio` for the same reason. In other words, the only correct command line is `@echo off` which is the only command line which should not be used on developing a batch file and [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) it on not working as expected. The second line should be `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` to completely define the __required__ execution environment.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 : `call(` is nonsense - to `call` a routine, you need either `call :internallabel` or `call otherbatchfile`. To nest the `for`s, change `call(` to `(` and add the closing `)` for each - so two `)`s at the end.

Problem 2 : the syntax `(step,100,1000)` is incorrect. You need `(%step%,100,1000)` - use the *contents* of `step`.

Problem 2a: The syntax of `for /L` is `for /L (startvalue,step,endvalue)...` Your variable name appears to assume otherwise.

Problem 3 : The `set var=value` syntax is for a *string* assignment, and is preferably `set "var=value"` to avoid assignment of unwanted trailing spaces. To perform a calculation, you need `set /A` and quotes are not required.

Problem 4 : The ever-faithful [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Having read & digested the information in (4), there's a few little things that can be noted:

In summary, `%var%` will be interpreted as the value of `var` **at the time the entire compound statement (starting in this case at `for...%%A...`)** was encountered. `!var!` is the value as it has been changed during the loop (the instantaneous or current value).

`set /a` *always* uses the *current* value of variables, so using `!var!` within a `set /a` formula is superfluous - `var` will suffice. `%var%` however will substitute the starting value of `var`.