# Chocolatey - `Msys2` library already installed

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have Windows OS (Operating System) and I am trying to install libpostal library https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

I noticed that there a lot of steps required to correctly install libpostal.  I want to take care of all installation steps using a .bat script and then try to run an example address.

I already post question here [run .bat files for python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903541/run-bat-files-for-python-libraries) , now I try to use suggestions to improve script:

```bash
@echo off

REM Check if MSYS2 and MinGW are installed
where msys2 2>nul >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo MSYS2 is already installed. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Install MSYS2 and MinGW
    choco install msys2
    refreshenv
)

REM Check if MSYS2 packages are updated
pacman -Qu 2>nul >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo MSYS2 packages are already updated. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Update MSYS2 packages
    pacman -Syu
)
    
REM Check if build dependencies are installed
pacman -Q autoconf automake curl git make libtool gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 2>nul >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Build dependencies are already installed. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Install build dependencies
    pacman -S autoconf automake curl git make libtool gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
)

REM Check if libpostal is cloned
if exist libpostal (
    echo libpostal repository is already cloned. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Clone libpostal repository
    git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal
)

cd libpostal

REM Check if libpostal is built and installed
if exist C:/Program Files/libpostal/bin/libpostal.dll (
    echo libpostal is already built and installed. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Build and install libpostal
    cp -rf windows/* ./
    ./bootstrap.sh
    ./configure --datadir=C:/libpostal
    make -j4
    make install
)
    
REM Check if libpostal is added to PATH environment variable
setx /m PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\libpostal\bin" 2>nul >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo libpostal is already added to PATH environment variable. Use --force to reinstall.
) else (
    REM Add libpostal to PATH environment variable
    setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\libpostal\bin"
)

REM Test libpostal installation
libpostal "100 S Broad St, Philadelphia, PA"

pause
```

Here is the log:

[image]

I think there might be problems because I already tried to install some of these programs (example MSYS2) in the past... this is why I try and write code to skip installation and updates if already exists.

I am stuck - how to proceed?

Comment: What is your specific programming code question? **how to proceed?** is not an on topic, focused, or appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd suggest `where mysys2.exe`

Comment: what do i replace with mysys2.exe?

Comment: It says right in the screenshot you posted that you need to use the `--force` flag to install it anyway.