# Bat - Script - If + loop + array (i and j) - blank cmd window shows up instead of running the programs | I want to keep the i and j loops

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

Opening empty cmd windows instead of the cmd commands being started

```
`@echo off
REM The echo off and other things don't work with power shell, only with cmd, another reason why wasn't working
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set FileTasks[0]=1 - Open task manager.
set FileTasks[1]=2 - Open event viewer.
set FileTasks[2]=3 - Open resources monitoring.
set FileTasks[3]=4 - Open performance monitoring.

set Task[0]=taskmgr
set Task[1]=eventvwr
set Task[2]=resmon
set Task[3]=perfmon

REM Main Script
echo Good morning, what is your name?
set /p Input_name=Name:
echo Hey %Input_name%, my name is bat the helper, here are the following 4 tasks I am able to execute if you wish.
echo Please type 1 - 4 to choose the wanted task:

REM Beginning of Function
:show_options_tasks
for /L %%i in (0,1,3) do (
    echo !FileTasks[%%i]!
REM The "!" is responsible to let the system get the values from the loop, that is why wasn't working before, differently from other  programming languages. Also keep the "%% within the brackets with the i"
)
REM End of Function

set /p Input_choice=Answer:

REM Beginning of Function
:first_interaction_complete_task
REM Selection of desired task
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
    if "!Input_choice!" == "!%%i!" (
        for /L %%j in (0,1,0) do (
            echo Thanks, you should see the requested program open in a new window!
            start !Task[%%i-1]!
            timeout /t 10 /nobreak > nul
            
        )
    )
)
REM End of Function
exit /b`
```

Opening empty cmd windows instead of the cmd commands being started. I want to keep the loops if possible, but open to different approaches also.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) The usage of the Windows command __CHOICE__ instead of __SET /P__ would be much better and much easier to process further if the environment variables are defined with `[1]` to `[4]` and there is used after the `choice` command line `if not errorlevel 1 goto show_options_tasks` and next the command line `start !Task[%ERRORLEVEL%]!`.

Comment: You haven't created any variable names ending with `-1]`, so obviously you are running ```start ```. That aside, stop being lazy and expecting the system to do additional work for you, and subject to specific settings not having been altered. `taskmgr`, `eventvwr`, `resmon`, `perfmon` and `timeout`, should be `%SystemRoot%\System32\Taskmgr.exe`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\eventvwr.exe`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\resmon.exe`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\perfmon.exe` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` respectively, _(especially as `eventvwr.msc` and `perfmon.msc` exist too)_.

Comment: `%%i-1` does not work. The evaluation of an arithmetic expression is possible only with `set /A`. It is not possible to write anywhere in a command line `%%i-1` and expect that `cmd.exe` processing the batch file detects that as arithmetic expression to evaluate during parsing the command line. See also [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) `exit /b` at the end of a batch file is useless and should be removed for that reason.

Comment: Although zero-based arrays are the standard in C-like languages, using base-one arrays in Batch files makes things simpler...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this:

```
@echo off
echo Good morning, what is your name?
set /p name=Name:
set Tasks= "task manager" "event viewer" "resources monitoring" "performance monitoring" ^
"CommandLine" "CommandLine New Window" "Batch Helper"
set Comms="taskmgr" "eventvwr" "resmon" "perfmon" "cmd /k" "start cmd" "Help"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:Demo
CLS
CALL :MENU %Tasks%
CALL :COMMANDS %Comms%
CALL :CHOSE
if "%Command%"=="Help" (call :Helper) else (%Command%)
Goto :Demo

:Helper
echo Hey %name%, my name is bat the helper.
echo Here are the following I am able to execute if you wish.
echo Please type number to choose the wanted task.
rem if want to exit from "cmd /k" menu, just type "exit" manually and will back to main menu
pause& exit /b

================================================================================================
REM @squashman : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman
:MENU
set /a n=0& set choices=
FOR %%I IN (%*) do (set /a n+=1& call :ResolveChar !n!& echo [!retval!] %%~I)
GOTO :EOF
:COMMANDS
set /a N=0& set choices=
FOR %%I IN (%Comms%) do (set /a N+=1& call :ResolveChar !N!& ^
set Options!retval!=%%~I& set choices=!choices!!retval!)
GOTO :EOF
:ResolveChar
SETLOCAL
set keys=_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
set _startchar=%1
CALL SET char=%%keys:~%_startchar%,1%%
ENDLOCAL & SET retval=%char%
goto :eof
:CHOSE
choice /c !choices! /m "Choose: " &rem /n
set num=%errorlevel%
call :ResolveChar %errorlevel%
set Command=!Options%retval%!
rem echo Choosen: [%retval%:%num%] %Command%
GOTO :EOF
```

Output:

```
[1] task manager
[2] event viewer
[3] resources monitoring
[4] performance monitoring
[5] CommandLine
[6] CommandLine New Window
[7] Batch Helper
Choose: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]?
```

PowerShell:

```
# OpenTasks.ps1
function OpenTasks {
    $Tasks = @( 'task manager', 'event viewer', 'resources monitoring', 'performance monitoring', 'CommandLine', 'Batch Helper' )
    $Comms = @( 'taskmgr', 'eventvwr', 'resmon', 'perfmon', '_cmd', 'Help' )
    $Opts  = @( 1..9; 0; 65..90 | foreach {[char]$_} )
    Clear-Host
    for ( $n=0; $n -lt $Tasks.Count; $n++ ) { "[$($Opts[$n])] $($Tasks[$n])" }
    $Choices = -join $Opts[0..($n - 1)]
    choice /c $Choices /m 'Choose:'
    $Comm = $Comms[($lastexitcode - 1)]
        if ( $Comm -eq 'Help' ) { Helper }
    elseif ( $Comm -eq '_cmd' ) { CommandLine }
    else                        { start $Comm }
    OpenTasks
}

function CommandLine {
    '[C] CMD | [P] PowerShell | [B] Back'
    choice /n /c 'cpb'
    switch ( $lastexitcode ) { 1 { cmd }; 2 { PowerShell } }
    # if want to exit from "CommandLine", just type "exit" manually and will back to main menu
}

function Helper {
    "`nGood morning, what is your name?"
    $name  = Read-Host 'Name'
    "Hey $name, my name is bat the helper."
    'Here are the following I am able to execute if you wish.'
    'Please type number to choose the wanted task.'
    Pause
}

# Dont delete this
OpenTasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following and works perfectly.

```
    @echo off
REM The echo off and other things don't work with PowerShell, only with cmd, another reason why it wasn't working

REM Main Script
:Name
echo Good morning, what is your name?
set /p Input_name=Name:
echo Hey %Input_name%, my name is bat the helper, here are the following 4 tasks I am able to execute if you wish.
echo Please type 1 - 4 to choose the wanted task:

REM Beginning of Function
:show_options_tasks
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FileTasks[0]=1 - Open task manager.
set FileTasks[1]=2 - Open event viewer.
set FileTasks[2]=3 - Open resources monitoring.
set FileTasks[3]=4 - Open performance monitoring.
for /L %%i in (0,1,3) do (
    echo !FileTasks[%%i]!
REM The "!" is responsible to let the system get the values from the loop, that is why it wasn't working before, differently from other programming languages. Also keep the "%% within the brackets with the i"
)
endlocal
REM End of Function

REM Beginning of Function
:first_interaction_complete_task
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p Input_choice=Answer:
set /a Input_choicenumber=%Input_choice%
REM Selection of desired task
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
    if !Input_choicenumber! equ %%i (
    set Task[0]=:Name
    set Task[1]=taskmgr
    set Task[2]=eventvwr
    set Task[3]=resmon
    set Task[4]=perfmon
        echo Thanks, you should see the requested program open in a new window!
    
        start !Task[%Input_choicenumber%]!
        timeout /t 10 /nobreak > nul
        goto :end_loop
    ) else (
        echo Invalid number, restarting program now.
        goto :Name
    )
    
)

:end_loop
endlocal
REM End of Function
exit /b
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Is this solution different from [Bat - Script - If + loop + array (i and j) - blank cmd window shows up instead of running the programs | I want to keep the i and j loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095078/1839439)?