# s3browser CLI download command hangs/pause after finishing successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to automate download process using s3browser CLI within my batch file. I want to use s3browser-cli /file download one by one in one master batch file. **[Link to the doc from S3browser](https://s3browser.com/s3cmd.aspx)**

S3browser download command works but after download is finished it just hangs and can't continue to the next line of my batch file. I tried running only one download in the background and after it completes it should close the main window:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\S3 Browser"
s3browser-cli.exe /file download Account[secret_key]  "Source\file1.txt" "Destination\Filip" 
exit 0
```

*#tried with "call s3browser-cli.exe" and "start /b /wait" as well with the same effect*

but it displaying "Successfully downloaded" at the end and it hangs/pause unless I use Ctrl+C and type "N" so it skips and continue to the next line which is my "exit". File is downloaded, but I can't run multi "/file download" one after another unless I manually terminate each one. What am I doing wrong? Can this issue be from s3browser side? I'm new to S3 and batch. Hope I can get someone to help me.

PS I've tried running each commands in the same window, one batch file but separate windows, using call, start with and without /wait but every time the download is successful and it hangs/pause till i manually force it to quite which stops me from downloading multiply files one by one from different folders without my intervention.

**Here's the full batch file I'm working on:** *(each file is around 50-80GB)*

```
@echo off
type welcome-message.txt

if not defined relVer goto :labelNoVer
goto :commonexit

:labelNoVer
set /p relVer=Please input the version you want to download:

cd "C:\Program Files\S3 Browser"
s3browser-cli.exe /file download Account[secret_key]  "Source/%relVer%/file1.txt" "Destination\Filip" 
echo ----------------Copy-END for File 1---------------------

s3browser-cli.exe /file download Account[secret_key]  "Source/%relVer%/file2.txt" "Destination\Filip" 
echo ----------------Copy-END for File 2---------------------

s3browser-cli.exe /file download Account[secret_key]  "Source/%relVer%/file3.txt" "Destination\Filip" 
echo ----------------Copy-END for Everything---------------------
pause
exit

:commonexit
echo Terminating Copy!
pause
exit
```

Comment: The first advice I'd offer is to remove all instances of `start /wait`. Also `if defined relVer goto :labelYesVer` serves no purpose, as you have no `:labelYesVer` label, _and you specifically told us "Here's the full batch file"_!

Comment: @Compo thanks, I've edited my file and removed start /wait (I'm still having this issue without it as well or using call). That :labelYesVer was some leftover from another version but no need for it here, I removed it as well. thanks again

Comment: Well you can also now replace `if not defined relVer goto :labelNoVer`, `goto :commonexit`, and `:labelNoVer`, with `if defined relVer goto :commonexit`. The `call` command is **only** for running another batch file from a master batch file, or a label within itself, if the intention is to continue the script beyond that point. It is **never** needed to run an '.exe' file.

Comment: If you suspect that `s3browser-cli.exe` is the problem, then you can use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you, I'll look into that and try to use it tomorrow.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for clarifying that, I guess it might be the s3browser problem itself if I don't need to use call or anything with .exe.

Comment: Replace `cd "C:\Program Files\S3 Browser"` by `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"` as the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads` is definitely not write-protected for your account in comparison to `C:\Program Files\S3 Browser` which is most likely write-protected for your account. Modify all `s3browser-cli.exe /file download Account[secret_key] "Source/%relVer%/file1.txt" "Destination\Filip"` to `"%ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser\s3browser-cli.exe" /file download Account[secret_key] "Source\%relVer%\file1.txt" "Destination\Filip"` and make sure that `Source\%relVer%\file1.txt` and `Destination\Filip`

Comment: exist in directory `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads` instead of `%ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser` as the latter is now the current working directory and not anymore the write-protected program files directory of *S3 Browser*. Last remove the command `exit` which is always unnecessary and just counterproductive at the end of a batch file. The other should be `exit /B`. See also [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)