# Windows batch file REG ADD not working sometimes, but not all the time

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, registry

I have a batch file that the user is running which writes a value to their registry file (HKCU).
Sometimes the `REG ADD` works, sometimes it doesn't. For instance, the first time I trialled it on an end user, it didn't work (no errors though), I ran it again and it didn't work (still no errors), I ran it again and it worked. Weird...

These are the commands (obviously the variables have been defined earlier in the script):

```bash
SET "logFolder=%userprofile%\SomeCo\SomeCo - Documents\General\Email Signatures\04.InstalledLogs"
SET "outlookSigPath=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures"
SET "outlookRegProfile=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('whoami /upn') DO SET "userId=%%A"
SET "sigName=%userId%"
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Diagnostics\BootDiagnosticsData" /V "ProfileBeingOpened"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') DO SET "OutProfName=%%A"

REG ADD "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002" /v "New Signature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f
REG ADD "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002" /v "Reply-Forward Signature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening, and how best to fix it so it writes the correct values the first run?

**What I've tried:**
Rerunning the script helped, it eventually added the value to the registry. Running the same script on another computer didn't have any problems the first go.

I've added some logging on the script, e.g:

```bash
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%A in ('REG QUERY "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002" /v "New Signature"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') DO SET "RegNewSignature=%%A"
ECHO New Signature name set in Registry to: %RegNewSignature% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
```

The first time it ran, it gave a blank value. Then I ran it again and it gave the correct values.
I could maybe loop a `REG QUERY` and `IF`/`ELSE` statement like:

```bash
reg query mykey >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo "mykey exists- do nothing"
) else (
  echo "mykey does not exist - add the key and give it a value"
  reg add mykey
  reg add mykey /v value ...
)
```

Help very much appreciated!

Edit: Original script:

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
    REM To update, change path for "sigsFolder" in the variable definitions
    REM This script is run by the user to copy their pre-created htm Signature file from SharePoint, and then set that as their Signature in Outlook.

    REM Checks for log local log file path and creates a local log directory in C:\Temp folder  
IF exist C:\Temp\EmailSignatures ( ECHO  C:\Temp\ exists ) ELSE ( MKDIR C:\Temp\EmailSignatures )

    REM Sets the local log folder path
SET "localLogFolder=C:\Temp\EmailSignatures"

    REM Get the user principal name 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('whoami /upn') DO SET "userId=%%A"
ECHO Found user %userId% >"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Variable Definitions
    REM Also defines folder and registry keys for Outlook signatures
    REM To update, change path for "sigsFolder" 
ECHO Setting Variables >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "sigsFolder=%userprofile%\SomeCo\SomeCo - Documents\General\Email Signatures\03.SigFiles"
ECHO sigsFolder variable set to: %lsigsFolder% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "logFolder=%userprofile%\SomeCo\SomeCo - Documents\General\Email Signatures\04.InstalledLogs"
ECHO logFolder variable set to: %logFolder% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "outlookSigPath=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures"
ECHO outlookSigPath variable set to: %outlookSigPath% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "outlookRegProfile=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles"
ECHO outlookRegProfile variable set to: %outlookRegProfile% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "outlookRegMailSettings=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings"
ECHO outlookRegMailSettings variable set to: %outlookRegMailSettings% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "outlookRegFirstRunPath=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Setup"
ECHO outlookRegFirstRunPath variable set to: %outlookRegFirstRunPath% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

SET "sigName=%userId%"
ECHO sigName variable set to: %sigName% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Copy the user's signature to their local Outlook signatures folder
ECHO Copying your signature file >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
COPY /Y "%sigsFolder%\%userId%.htm" "%outlookSigPath%" >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Terminate any instance of outlook.exe
ECHO Terminating Outlook >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
TASKKILL /F /IM outlook.exe >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Remove the "First-Run" value from the Registry if it exists
ECHO Deleting Outlook First Run Keys >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
REG DELETE "%outlookRegFirstRunPath%" /v "First-Run" /f  >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Find Outlook signature Registry path
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Diagnostics\BootDiagnosticsData" /V "ProfileBeingOpened"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') DO SET "OutProfName=%%A"
ECHO Found Outlook Profile: %OutProfName% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Set the Outlook New and Reply signatures in the Registry - Outlook Profile path
ECHO Setting your Outlook signature in the Windows Registry >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
REG ADD "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"  /v "New Signature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
REG ADD "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"  /v "Reply-Forward Signature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%A in ('REG QUERY "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"  /v "New Signature"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') DO SET "RegNewSignature=%%A"
ECHO New Signature name set in Registry to: %RegNewSignature% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%A in ('REG QUERY "%outlookRegProfile%\%OutProfName%\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"  /v "Reply-Forward Signature"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') DO SET "RegReplySignature=%%A"
ECHO Reply and Forward Signature name set in Registry to: %RegReplySignature% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Set the signature names in the Registry - Outlook Mail Settings
    REM REG ADD "%outlookRegMailSettings%" /v "NewSignature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f
    REM REG ADD "%outlookRegMailSettings%" /v "ReplySignature" /t REG_SZ /d "%sigName%" /f

    REM Disable Outlook Roaming signatures to enable Outlook to use signatures on this device
ECHO Disabling Roaming Signatures >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Setup" /v "DisableRoamingSignaturesTemporaryToggle" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Setup"  /v "DisableRoamingSignaturesTemporaryToggle"  ^|findstr /ri "REG_DWORD"') DO SET "RegDisableRoamingSig=%%A"
ECHO Outlook Roaming Signatures Toggle set in Registry to: %RegDisableRoamingSig% >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Log to user logfile
REM IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (ECHO "ERROR - Finding Outlook Profile path" >>%logFolder%\%userId%.txt
REM ) ELSE
REM (ECHO "SUCCESS - Outlook Profile Path is %OutProfName%" >>%logFolder%\%userId%.txt)

ECHO Outlook Signature script completed >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"

    REM Copy log file from local computer to Installed Logs folder
COPY "%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log" "%logFolder%\" /Y
```

When I ran it for the user the first time the log file looked like this:

> ```
> Setting Variables
> sigsFolder variable set to: C:\Users\User\SomeCo\SomeCo - Documents\SomeCo\Admin\Email Signatures\UserSigs 
>
> logFolder variable set to: C:\Users\User\SomeCo\SomeCo - Documents\SomeCo\Admin\EmailSignatures\InstalledLogs 
>
> outlookSigPath variable set to:
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures 
>
> outlookRegProfile variable set to:
> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles 
>
> outlookRegMailSettings variable set to:
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings 
>
> outlookRegFirstRunPath variable set to:
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Setup  
>
> sigName variable set to: user@someco.com  
>
> Copying your signature file 
>         1 file(s) copied. 
> Terminating Outlook
> SUCCESS: The process "OUTLOOK.EXE" with PID 9136 has been terminated. 
> Deleting Outlook First Run Keys
> The operation completed successfully.
>
> Found Outlook Profile: Outlook
> Setting your Outlook signature in the Windows Registry  
> The operation completed successfully.
>
> The operation completed successfully.
>
> New Signature name set in Registry to:   
> Reply and Forward Signature name set in Registry to:   
> Disabling Roaming Signatures
> The operation completed successfully.
>
> Outlook Roaming Signatures Toggle set in Registry to: 0x1  Outlook
> Signature script completed
> ```

The script seemed to complete, but the settings Registry values for New Signature and Reply and Forward Signature are both blank in the output.
When I ran it a second and third time though, the log file showed the correct data in the log fil for these values.

Comment: If you want help with a code issue we need a [mcve]. Please [Edit] your question to include all of the code which defines the variables `%outlookRegProfile%`, `%OutProfName%`, `%sigName%`, `%localLogFolder%`, `%userId%`. I'd also advise that you use `3,*` for your `tokens`, then change `=%%A` to `=%%B`. There's no reason to pre-check when using the `/f` option with `ADD`. It either writes, overwrites, or fails with an error message. You have not indicated that there's an error message, so the only assumption is that you're tryng to use a value which first requires the registry to be refreshed.

Comment: I recommend reading the Microsoft documentation pages [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details), [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys). A batch file can be processed on 64-bit Windows by 64-bit `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` or by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`.

Comment: There is executed the 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe` on batch file processed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` because of the file system redirector on using in a batch file just `reg`. That could be important depending on the registry key defined by the environment variables `outlookRegProfile` and `OutProfName`. Well, the question was just updated and we know now `outlookRegProfile`. There is still not defined the environment variable `OutProfName`. It would be good in general to make sure that 64-bit `reg.exe` is used on running the batch file on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: There can be used in the batch file `if not exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe (set "REGEXE=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe") else set "REGEXE=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"`. The command lines beginning now with `REG` must begin with `%REGEXE%` for running always 64-bit `reg.exe` on 64-bit Windows and 32-bit `reg.exe` on 32-bit Windows using the correct fully qualified file name.

Comment: I would use `FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%I IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /UPN') DO SET "userId=%%I"` instead of `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('whoami /upn') DO SET "userId=%%A"` and `FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('%REGEXE% QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Diagnostics\BootDiagnosticsData" /V "ProfileBeingOpened"  ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "REG_SZ"') DO SET "OutProfName=%%~J"` instead of `FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\…"') DO SET "OutProfName=%%A"` for a batch file working independent on `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.

Comment: I do not see any reason why the `REG ADD` commands should not always work. The suggestions posted above make the batch file more fail safe as no longer depending on environment variables like `PATH` too often corrupted by users. I suppose the issue does not exist with this minimal, reproducible example batch file. The cause of the problem is most likely in one of the other lines in the batch file causing a syntax error on execution resulting in an exit of batch file processing by `cmd.exe` with an error message written to `STDERR`.

Comment: The error message can be seen only on running the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file. See [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564). I doubt that we can help on the issue which at least I cannot reproduce on my Windows PC having also Outlook 365 (Outlook 16.0) installed and the execution of `whoami` and `reg query` return both the correct strings.

Comment: Hint: On the PC where you think `REG ADD` was executed and failed to add the registry values, search the entire registry for a registry value with name `New Signature`. If you find this registry value in registry keys not expected by you, you could get an idea what is going wrong in the batch file resulting in adding this registry value to an unexpected registry key with creation of the unexpected registry key too.

Comment: Thanks!!! I've added the full original code and the log file output that shows the Registry values didn't get added, but the script completed.

Comment: In addition to my former suggestions I suggest further replacing `TASKKILL /F /IM outlook.exe` by `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM outlook.exe`. There is really no need to run __TASKKILL__ with its option `/F` to force a brutal kill of all running `outlook.exe` by the operating system. It is enough to run __TASKKILL__ without option `/F` for sending to all running `outlook.exe` the [WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) message for a graceful self-termination of Outlook.

Comment: I reviewed the entire batch file and ran it after inserting some `echo` left to commands which would modify files or registry values already present. I can't see anything which could result in registry values not added as expected by you. The output to console and to the produced log files looks fine. The missing values after `New Signature name set in Registry to:` and `Reply and Forward Signature name set in Registry to:` in log file are not explainable by me.

Comment: The symptoms described by you would be explainable if all that code would be inside a command block beginning with `(` and ending with a matching `)` because of `%RegNewSignature%` in `ECHO New Signature name set in Registry to: %RegNewSignature%` would be expanded already before running the first command in the command block which means before the environment variable `RegNewSignature` is defined at all resulting in `%RegNewSignature%` replaced by an empty string before `RED ADD` and `REG QUERY` with `SET "RegNewSignature=%%A"` are executed at all.

Comment: But there is no such command block defined in posted entire batch file even with the __REM__ command lines which are passed by `cmd.exe` as every other command line too. `IF exist C:\Temp\EmailSignatures` should be ``IF exist C:\Temp\EmailSignatures\`` for really checking for the existence of the __folder__ `C:\Temp\EmailSignatures` and not *any file system entry* (file/folder/link) with name `EmailSignatures` in directory `C:\Temp`.

Comment: The three lines `REM IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (ECHO "ERROR - Finding Outlook Profile path" >>%logFolder%\%userId%.txt`, `REM ) ELSE` and `REM (ECHO "SUCCESS - Outlook Profile Path is %OutProfName%" >>%logFolder%\%userId%.txt)` should be modified to the single line REM `(IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO ERROR - Finding Outlook Profile path) ELSE ECHO SUCCESS - Outlook Profile Path is "%OutProfName%") >>"%localLogFolder%\%userId%.log"`. But that does not really matter at the moment as the three lines are remark command lines.