# How to open a series of folders numbered 01-18

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to open a folder on every lab computer using a batch script. The computers are labeled 01,02,03-18. I didn't think there was a way to convert the number from 1 to 01 so I used an if statement. But I am getting an error that says `9 was unexpected at this time`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "z=0"
SET "n=9"
for /L %%x in (1,1,18) do (
  SET v=%%x
  IF %v% LEQ %n%
  (
    SET num=%z%%v%
  ) ELSE (
    SET num=%v%
  )
  start "" "\\lab-!num!\
  pause
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with the placement of th parenthesis (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476)), and an inconsistent usage of the delayed expansion (you are using `!num!` but not `!v!`, the two variables that change inside the code block) but the code can be simplified by including the padding in the values of the `for` loop

```
for /l %%x in (1001, 1, 1018) do (
    set "num=%%x"
    start "" "\\lab-!num:~-2!\share\folder"
)
```

Comment: Very clever I wish I thought of that. My knowledge of batch is spotty, and I never can remember how to deal with variables.

Answer (score 1):

When `delayed expansion` is enabled, use exclamation marks inside for loops.
And don't forget that open parenthesis must be on the same line as the `if`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "z=0"
SET "n=9"
for /L %%x in (1,1,3) do (
  SET v=%%x
  IF !v! LEQ !n! (
    SET num=!z!!v!
  ) ELSE (
    SET num=!v!
  )
  start \\lab-!num!\
  pause
)
```