# File deletion using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete files older than certain number of days, based on their names' pattern, using a batch script. I also want to check beforehand, whether the files exist or not. I'm using the following code:

```
if exist "C:\Users\John\Documents\Week*" 
(
forfiles /D -30 /C "cmd /c del C:\Users\John\Documents\Week*"
) 
else (exit)
```

However nothing is happening.

Comment: just try with `del /q "C:\Users\John\Documents\Week*" 2>nul`

Comment: forfiles /d -30 /c "something" with do the same "something" for each file older than 30 days.  In your case if C:\Users\John\Documents\Week* matches anything ALL of them will be deleted once for every file in the current directory that is older than 30 days - if there are 10 files in the current directory older than 30 days you are deleting ALL files matching C:\Users\John\Documents\Week* 10 times.

Comment: @npocmaka unless I am completely wrong he doesn't want to delete all files matching that pattern - just the ones that are older than 30 days.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476) could help

Comment: As pointed out by @MCND the parenthesis indentation was wrong. After correcting it the script ran. However, all files resembling the pattern Week* are getting deleted.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Am new to batch scripting. Can you please explain your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executing the `del` with a mask that includes all the matching files. You need to let `forfiles` to search the files and execute the deletion for each of them.

You can try with something like

```dos
if exist "C:\Users\John\Documents\Week*" (
    forfiles /D -30 /P "C:\Users\John\Documents" /M "Week*" /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
) else ( exit )
```

Comment: It worked. But had to remove the quotes from the path. Thanks @MCND

Comment: @John, sorry, I included an ending backslash in the path that should not be present (it is escaping the quote). Removed.