# batch file net use with for output for variable if

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, findstr, net-use

I have code for mapping drive in windows with batch file, i use parameter like nik and password. Then if the user and password match the program will give output "Success" and else it the program will give output "some error". The parameters for output Success and some error i got from net use with FOR DO and FIND

@MC ND

here

```
:MENU
Title MyTitle
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO OFF

Echo --------------- MENU -----------------------
Echo 1. Press 1 for start or reload program.
Echo 2. Press 0 for exit.

Echo Choose :
SET /p tekan=
IF %tekan%==0 GOTO EXIT
IF %tekan%==1 GOTO FORM_QMR

:FORM_QMR
Echo ---------- Fill this Form (%userdomain%) ----------
SET /p nik="Insert Your ID :"
SET /p passwd="Insert Your Password :"
GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION

IF %userdomain% == DOMAIN GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITH_DOMAIN
IF NOT %userdomain% == DOMAIN GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITHOUT_DOMAIN

:CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITH_DOMAIN
FOR /F %%H IN ('NET USE "\\myserver\Path01\Path02" /User:domain\%nik% %passwd% 2^>^&1 ^| Find /I "System error 1326 has occurred."') DO SET "ACTSTATUS=BAD"
IF %ACTSTATUS%==BAD
(
Echo "Some error found, please contact administrator."
GOTO FORM_QMR
)
IF NOT %ACTSTATUS%==BAD
(
Echo "Success."
)

:CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITHOUT_DOMAIN
FOR /F %%H IN ('NET USE "\\192.168.1.1\Path01\Path02" /User:domain\%nik% %passwd% 2^>^&1 ^| Find /I "System error 1326 has occurred."') DO SET "ACTSTATUS=BAD"
IF %ACTSTATUS%==BAD
(
Echo "Some error found, please contact administrator."
GOTO FORM_QMR
)
IF NOT %ACTSTATUS%==BAD(
Echo "Success."
)

:EXIT
exit
```

my problem after insert password, the program always send output "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

can anyone helpme..

Comment: 1) Please, post code, not images, 2) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes corrected in the following code snippet (commented if necessary):

```
:FORM_QMR
Echo ---------- Fill this Form (%userdomain%) ----------
SET /p nik="Insert Your ID :"
SET /p passwd="Insert Your Password :"
rem      CREDENTIAL_ACTION label not found
rem GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION

SET "ACTSTATUS=BAD"
IF %userdomain% == DOMAIN ( 
     GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITH_DOMAIN
) else (
     GOTO CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITHOUT_DOMAIN
)

:CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITH_DOMAIN
rem note double quoted password and "delims=" option
FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('
  NET USE "\\myserver\Path01\Path02" /User:domain\%nik% "%passwd%" 2^>NUL ^| Find /I "The command completed successfully"
') DO SET "ACTSTATUS=GOOD"
goto :common

:CREDENTIAL_ACTION_FOR_USER_WITHOUT_DOMAIN
rem note double quoted password and "delims=" option
FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('
  NET USE "\\192.168.1.1\Path01\Path02" /User:domain\%nik% "%passwd%" 2^>NUL ^| Find /I "The command completed successfully"
') DO SET "ACTSTATUS=GOOD"

:common
rem note parentheses and double quotes
IF "%ACTSTATUS%"=="BAD" (
    Echo "Some error found, please contact administrator."
    GOTO FORM_QMR
) else (
    Echo "Success."
)
```

Another approach with less `GOTO`s utilises `ERRORLEVEL` set by `choice.exe` and `net.exe`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:MENU
Title MyTitle

Echo --------------- MENU -----------------------
Echo Press 1 for start or reload program.
Echo Press 0 for exit.
Echo Choose:

CHOICE /C 10 /M "Press 1 for start or reload program, 0 for exit."
IF errorlevel 2 GOTO EXIT

:FORM_QMR
Echo ---------- Fill this Form (%userdomain%) ----------
SET /p nik="Insert Your ID :"
SET /p passwd="Insert Your Password :"

IF %userdomain% == DOMAIN ( 
     set "_shar=\\myserver\Path01\Path02"
     set "_user=/User:domain\%nik%"
) else (
     set "_shar=\\192.168.1.1\Path01\Path02"
     set "_user=/User:domain\%nik%"
)

>NUL 2>&1 NET USE "%_shar%" %_user% "%passwd%"&&SET "ACTSTATUS=OK"||SET "ACTSTATUS=BAD"

IF "%ACTSTATUS%"=="BAD" (
    Echo "Some error found, please contact administrator."
    GOTO FORM_QMR
) else (
    Echo "Success."
)
:EXIT
```

Explanation:

- [`CHOICE.exe` Accept user input to a batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), see also `choice /?`.
- `&&` and `||`: [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: why **:common** always return SUCCESS ??

Comment: @ikwijaya My inadvertency, sorry. `2^>NUL` instead of `2^>^&1` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The `(` must be on the same physical line as its associated `if`.

The same comment goes for `do`

and `else` must be `) else (`

No if, buts or maybes (except for more experienced users...)