# Batch file choice loop on unexpected input

Tags: batch-file, batch-choice

So I have this choice:

```
echo.
echo  All done. What would you like to do next?
echo  1. Open output folder
echo  2. Exit
echo.

set /p Choose=" Select 1 or 2 and press Enter: "

if '%Choose%'==1 goto show
if '%Choose%'==2 goto end
```

The problem is, this script detect any other choice other than `2` as `1`, which is not how I want it. Instead, I want it to loop back to `choice` on unexpected input. The closest thing the internet told me is:

```
if '%Choose%'NEQ 1 if '%Choose%'NEQ 2 goto choice
```

But this goes to choice on ANY input, even `1` or `2`.

Comment: [`if "%choose%"=="1"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690924/2861476)

Comment: Use the command `choice` instead of `set /P` and you don't have this problem anymore. Run in a command prompt window `choice /?` for help.

Comment: Both sides of an `if` must be identical for `==` to become true. You've single-quoted the first, so you must single-quote the second. Actually, double-quote `"` both sides for safety. If both `if` statements fail, then the choice made is neither, so `goto` your first `echo`. Speaking of `choice` - you should look that up as another way to get the job done. Plenty of examples on SO - just use the `search` box in the top line

Comment: @Mofi That uses `ERRORLEVEL` which is used somewhere else in the script. I don't know batch script good enough to mess with that.

Comment: @Magoo that did the trick, thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can set it as such? Unless, this is gonna be marked as duplicate. Also, this is an already existing script that I'm trying to customize for myself, so I didn't come up with `set /p`. That's what the author of the script chose.

Comment: `errorlevel` is updated by nearly any command executed within the batch file. It holds the exit code of the previously executed command or executable. So it only matters which command/executable was executed just before the line containing `if errorlevel` and not what was executed 20 lines above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides of an if must be identical for == to become true. You've single-quoted the first, so you must single-quote the second. Actually, double-quote " both sides for safety. If both if statements fail, then the choice made is neither, so goto your first echo. Speaking of choice - you should look that up as another way to get the job done. Plenty of examples on SO - just use the search box in the top line

Comment: @GeorgeHovhannisian Please note that on many keyboards pressing Shift+2 instead of just 2 results in entering `"` character. So if a user enters by mistake `"` because of Shift is hold (or CapsLock is active depending on keyboard layout) and press next RETURN, the batch file processing is exited by Windows command interpreter because of a syntax error as the result is `if """ == "1" goto show` which is an invalid command line. It is really hard to make `set /P` input fail safe against typing mistakes by the user. For simple selections from a list `choice` is definitely the better __choice__.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code any the user can't press anything else than 1 or 2 (or Ctrl+C to break batch file execution) with immediate continuation of script processing after having hit key <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd>.

```
@echo off
echo/
echo  All done. What would you like to do next?
echo/
echo  1. Open output folder
echo  2. Exit
echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12 /N /M "Select 1 or 2: "
if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF

rem Code to run on open output folder.
echo Use selected 1.
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`

Read also the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) why it is here enough to use only `if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF` as the only remaining option is that `errorlevel` has value 1 after execution of `choice`.

And read also DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) why it is better to use `echo/` instead of `echo.` to output an empty line.

Read also:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)