# BATCH exist not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I've started making a small program in Batch, it worked fine until I've gotten into `IF NOT EXIST`, just then all my problems started as every time it got into that statement, the batch file has just crashed.
Here's the code:

```
REM BEGGINING OPTIONS
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Organizer
COLOR 07
MODE CON COLS=101 LINES=30
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
CLS

REM WELCOME
CLS
COLOR E
ECHO WELCOME TO ORGANIZER.BAT! THIS PROGRAM IS MADE BY ELDAR BAKERMAN TO ORGANIZE YOUR FILES AND COMPUTER!
ECHO THIS IS VERSION 1.0!
ECHO THIS PROJECT STARTED IN 11.08.2017 (DD/MM/YYYY)
ECHO PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE
PAUSE>NUL

REM ORGANIZATION
:ORGANIZATION
COLOR 0B
CLS
REM CREATE FOLDERNAME VARIABLE
SET /P FOLDERNAME=WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE FOLDER WHERE THE UNORGANIZED FILES ARE LOCATED IN? 


REM FIND FOLDER
IF NOT EXIST "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\%FOLDERNAME%\NUL"
(
COLOR 0C
ECHO ERROR! FOLDER "%FOLDERNAME%" WAS NOT FOUND!
PAUSE>NUL
) ELSE (
PAUSE
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Wrong parenthesis placement. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476) could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your script without the bloat:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET/P "FOLDERNAME=WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE UNORGANIZED FILES FOLDER? "
IF NOT EXIST "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\%FOLDERNAME%\" (
    ECHO ERROR! FOLDER "%FOLDERNAME%" WAS NOT FOUND!
) ELSE ECHO "%FOLDERNAME%" WAS FOUND
PAUSE
```

Hopefully you can see how the parenthesis placement works.